How to convert JSON to a generic struct in Go using interface{} without getting a map[string]interface{}?
I'm trying to convert JSON to a generic struct in Go, where the struct can have fields with varied types. To handle different types of data, I'm using the interface{} type in the struct fields. However, I don't know the exact structure of the JSON object that will be unmarshalled, so I need a flexible solution. When I unmarshal the JSON, I end up with a map[string]interface{}, but I want to get an object (struct).
For example, given this JSON:
{
  "animal": "Elephant",
  "age": 15,
  "location": {
    "country": "Kenya",
    "continent": "Africa"
  },
  "diet": ["grass", "fruit", "vegetables"]
}

Here is the Go code I am using:
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    jsonData := `{
        "animal": "Elephant",
        "age": 15,
        "location": {
            "country": "Kenya",
            "continent": "Africa"
        },
        "diet": ["grass", "fruit", "vegetables"]
    }`
    
    var result interface{}
    
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }
    
    fmt.Printf("Result: %+v\n", result)
}

Instead of getting a map[string]interface{}, I want to directly unmarshal into a struct with interface{} fields, so that I can handle the varied types more easily.
Current output:
map[age:15 animal:Elephant diet:[grass fruit vegetables] location:map[continent:Africa country:Kenya]]

Desired output (as an object):
{Animal:Elephant Age:15 Location:{Country:Kenya Continent:Africa} Diet:[grass fruit vegetables]}

I tried using mapstructure.Decode(data, &result) but it didn't work either.
How can I achieve this in Go? Am I missing some Go concept to make this work correctly?

A JSON object is a map of strings to arbitrary values; map[string]interface{} is exactly the data structure you would expect. I'm not clear what sort of difficulty this creates that you wouldn't also have with your desired behavior.

The problem is that there are some packages in the project that only work with structs and do not work with map[string]interface{}.

I don’t think the standard library has a way to do this, because there’s no way to know which underlying type to generate in general. What are you using to distinguish which struct the incoming data corresponds to? One (inefficient) approach would be to unmarshal generically to a map, check what type it is, then unmarshal again to the desired type.

Your current response is what one would expect from json unmarshalling. To map it to struct you need to do extra work.

"I'm trying to convert JSON to a generic struct in Go" There is no such thing like "a generic struct in Go" so your endavour is doomed to fail. Redesign.

You can use reflect to implement it, there is a example:
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    jsonData := `{
        "animal": "Elephant",
        "age": 15,
        "location": {
            "country": "Kenya",
            "continent": "Africa"
        },
        "diet": ["grass", "fruit", "vegetables"]
    }`

    var result any
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }

    data, _ := newVal(reflect.ValueOf(result))

    fmt.Printf("Result: %+v\n", data)
}

func newVal(val reflect.Value) (data reflect.Value, typ reflect.Type) {
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
        val = val.Elem()
    }
    switch val.Kind() {
    case reflect.String:
        return val, reflect.TypeOf("")
    case reflect.Int:
        return val, reflect.TypeOf(0)
    case reflect.Map:
        return newStruct(val)
    case reflect.Slice:
        return newSlice(val)
    case reflect.Float64:
        return val, reflect.TypeOf(0.0)
    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("not support yet: %s", val.Kind().String()))
    }
}

func newStruct(val reflect.Value) (data reflect.Value, typ reflect.Type) {
    if val.Kind() != reflect.Map {
        panic("not a map")
    }
    var fields []reflect.StructField
    var datas []reflect.Value
    iter := val.MapRange()
    for iter.Next() {
        data, typ := newVal(iter.Value())
        fields = append(fields, reflect.StructField{
            Name: upperFirstChar(iter.Key().String()),
            Type: typ,
            Tag:  reflect.StructTag(fmt.Sprintf(`json:"%s"`, iter.Key())),
        })
        datas = append(datas, data)
    }
    // Create a new struct type
    structType := reflect.StructOf(fields)

    // Create an instance of the struct
    structInstance := reflect.New(structType).Elem()

    // Set the values of the struct fields
    for i, data := range datas {
        structInstance.Field(i).Set(data)
    }
    return structInstance, structType
}

func newSlice(val reflect.Value) (data reflect.Value, typ reflect.Type) {
    if val.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("not a slice")
    }
    if val.Len() == 0 {
        // return empty slice
        return val, val.Type()
    }

    _, elemType := newVal(val.Index(0))
    slic := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(elemType), val.Len(), val.Len())
    for i := 0; i < val.Len(); i++ {
        elemData, _ := newVal(val.Index(i))
        slic.Index(i).Set(elemData)
    }
    return slic, slic.Type()
}

func upperFirstChar(s string) string {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return s
    }
    runes := []rune(s)
    runes[0] = unicode.ToUpper(runes[0])
    return string(runes)
}

After run, it will output :
Result: {Age:15 Location:{Country:Kenya Continent:Africa} Diet:[grass fruit vegetables] Animal:Elephant}

